# Get position item of list view error

Tags: java, android, listview

```
listContent.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()
    {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            for(int i=0;i<showLists.size();i++){
              //
                TextView v=(TextView)listContent.getChildAt(i).findViewById(R.id.txtDes);
                v.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);

            }

            TextView v=(TextView)listContent.getChildAt(position).findViewById(R.id.txtDes);
            v.setTextColor(Color.RED);
            Toast.makeText(context,"POS "+showLists.get(position).getDes(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });
```

I have been the problem with get position item of listview. Android just has shown about 12 row on devide's creen, when I click another item on listview (my listview have 30 item ) which shown the error.
 And this is error:
***"Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.view.View.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference" .
Thanks for read.***

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 0):

Your question is indeed about [Null Pointer Exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it), but is harder to identify why this is happening. The problem can be found here:

```
for(int i=0;i<showLists.size();i++){ <-- this line actually causes the crash
//
    the crash is in the next line, at the findViewById
    TextView v=(TextView)listContent.getChildAt(i).findViewById(R.id.txtDes); 
    v.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
}
```

Your `for` has the wrong upper limit because of a mechanism known as [recycling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11945563/how-listviews-recycling-mechanism-works), and because of this mechanism your list view **will never** have the same number of rows as the amount of data that needs to be displayed (read about recycling to understand this). Given this fact, we know for sure that the number of views found in list view (`listContent.getChildCount()`) will be smaller than `showLists.size()` and thus making the call `listContent.getChildAt(i)` to return a `NULL` value when the index equals `listContent.getChildCount()` creating the crash.

Now you might be tempted to change `showLists.size()` with `listContent.getChildCount()` and see that the app doesn't crash anymore, but if you click a row, then other rows are coloured also as you scroll the list (the recycling is again the problem). To really fix the problem you should save the index of the selected row and call `notifyDatasetChanged`, so when `getView` is called in adapter you simply check the current position to be displayed with the selected position. In case of equality you change the color of text to red, otherwise to black. Below, you will find some parts of an example:

```
int currentPosition = -1;

// Just a basic adapter. The getView method is the key here
final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1) {
        @NonNull
        @Override
        public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
            View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
            if (position == currentPosition) {
                ((TextView) view).setTextColor(Color.RED);
            } else {
                ((TextView) view).setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
            }
            return  view;
        }
    };

// and here is the onItemClick
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()
    {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            currentPosition = position;
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks, I have known that the list view had mechanism as recyling. When I click a item on listview(30 items) example item have index=0, hmm, even 2 items below this marker RED too. Can you fix it?

Comment: sorry, I read this comment so late. Thanks and I'll try it now.

Comment: No problem. Let me know if you need any help

Comment: I tried this code, and all of item listview set color red or my code was wrong. @@

Comment: I have just posted new cmt, pls check again :D

Comment: Check the `if` where you set the color. On each branch you are setting the color to red. Change the second one to black.

Comment: ah,I fixed it, but not working. It didn't call back method getView(...), and don't change currentposition. The object "final customListMoiNhat customListMoiNhat" I set final, this is my problem.

Comment: Can you post the adapter code here: https://ideone.com ? After post a comment with the link.

Answer (score 0):

```
listContent.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            for (int i = 0; i < showLists.size(); i++) {

                TextView v = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtDes);
                v.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);

            }

            TextView v = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtDes);
            v.setTextColor(Color.RED);
            Toast.makeText(context, "POS " + showLists.get(position).getDes(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });
```

Comment: This will still crash.

Answer (score 0):

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    LayoutInflater inflater= (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View viewRow=convertView;
    if(viewRow==null){
        viewRow=inflater.inflate(layout,parent,false);
        viewHolder viewHolder=new viewHolder();
        viewHolder.imgIcon    = (ImageView) viewRow.findViewById(R.id.imgIcon);
        viewHolder.txtDes     = (TextView) viewRow.findViewById(R.id.txtDes);

        viewRow.setTag(viewHolder);
    }

    viewHolder  holder= (viewHolder) viewRow.getTag();
    holder.imgIcon.setImageResource(listMoiNhat.get(position).getIcon());
    holder.txtDes.setText(listMoiNhat.get(position).getDes());
    if(position==currentpos){
        holder.txtDes.setTextColor(Color.RED);
    }
    else {
        holder.txtDes.setTextColor(Color.RED);

    }
    return viewRow;
}
```

//and here is create customListMoiNhat object
        final customListMoiNhat customListMoiNhat=new customListMoiNhat(context,R.layout.moinhat_customlistview,showLists,currentpos);
        customListMoiNhat.notifyDataSetChanged();
        listContent.setAdapter(customListMoiNhat);

```
    listContent.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()
    {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {



            currentpos=position;
            customListMoiNhat.notifyDataSetChanged();


        }
    });
```